# VSCode python file becomes empty but still has 376 bytes size

Tags: python, file, visual-studio-code, filesystems, recovery

I was writing a file in Jupyter notebook in vscode days ago. I've run each cell several times and definitely saved it before. I didn't close the file on vscode, and when I open my computer today, I think I clicked on the update without closing the file. Then my file became empty; all codes were gone. I surely didn't delete it, and I couldn't find anything on my backups either. However, when I check the info on my file, it says it has 376 bytes. Can anyone help me find my code? I've tried to open this file on other platforms as well, but they all show my file is empty. Can anyone help me find the codes back?

I checked the trash, Library/Application Support/Code/Backups, and timeline. Nothing was found. I also checked malware, but no virus was found as well.

I'm using a mac btw.

Comment: Most likely a damaged file system and not a programming issue.

Comment: how can I fix that? Could you please give me more hints? Thx